# Editing Text File in Ruby and Python

Tags: python, ruby, text-files, read-write

I was able to handle the following text file editing by "RUBY" and I have a problem when it was changed to "PYTHON".
I have a template file and it is modified by code. Skipping lines and cloning lines and replacing data were handled by "skip" and "get" variable in RUBY. In python, how can I do it? Could you please help me?

```
template.txt

$$$111$$$
$$$222$$$
Application $$$000$$$
User_id $$$001$$$
$$$333$$$
$$$444$$$
Deployment
```

```
template_output.txt

Application FORM
User_id A0001
Application FORM
User_id B0002
Application FORM
User_id C7030
```

```
main.rb

read_line = []

File.open("template.txt") { |f| read_line = f.readlines.map &:chomp }

write   = []
line2 = []
get   = 0
skip  = 0

test_id = ["A0001", "B0002", "C7030"]


read_line.each do | line |
    next    if line.lstrip[0] == '#'

    if line.include?("$$$111$$$")
        skip = 0
        next
    end

    if line.include?("$$$444$$$")
        skip = 1
        next
    end

    next if skip == 1

    if line.include?("$$$222$$$")
        line2.clear
        get = 1
        next
    end

    if line.include?("$$$333$$$")
        get = 0
        test_id.each do | cur |
          test = "#{cur}"
            line2.each do | row |
                write << row.gsub("$$$000$$$") { "FORM" }
                    .gsub("$$$001$$$") { "#{test}" }
            end
        end
        next
    end

    if get == 1
        line2.push(line)
        next
    end

    job << line
end

File.open("template_output.txt", "w") { |f| write.each { |s| f.puts(s) } }
```

```
main.py

write   = []
line2 = []
get   = 0
skip  = 0

with open("template.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("#"):
            continue

        if skip == 1:
            continue

        if get == 1:
            line2.append(line)
            continue

        if "$$$111$$$" in line:
            skip = 1
            continue

        if "$$$222$$$" in line:
            print("true")
            skip = 0
            continue

        write.append(line)


with open("template_output.txt", "w") as o:
    for item in write:
        o.write(str(item) + "\n")
```